# How to convert this function into a generator?

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a function (patch_generator) that takes two images (as numpy arrays) and generates patches give a window_size. The function works correctly but it generates all the patches at the same time. I want to generate image patches in batches.

```
def patch_generator(x, y, window_size):
    # x and y are numpy arrays with shape of: (bands, height, width)
    # generates image patch of shape (patches, size, size, bands)
    # and a ground truth patch of shape (patches,)
    index_patch = 0
    x = x.reshape((x.shape[1], x.shape[2], x.shape[0]))
    y = y.reshape((y.shape[1], y.shape[2], y.shape[0]))
    if window_size % 2 == 0:
        margin = int(window_size/2)
    else:
        margin = int((window_size - 1) / 2)
    x_zeros = pad_zeros(x, margin)
    x_patch = np.zeros((x.shape[0]*x.shape[1], window_size, window_size, x.shape[2]))
    y_patch = np.zeros((x.shape[0]*x.shape[1]))
    row_range = range(margin, x_zeros.shape[0] - margin)
    col_range = range(margin, x_zeros.shape[1] - margin)
    for r in product(row_range, col_range):
        if window_size % 2 == 0:
            patch = x_zeros[r[0] - margin:r[0] + margin,
                            r[1] - margin:r[1] + margin]
        else:
            patch = x_zeros[r[0] - margin:r[0]+margin+1,
                            r[1] - margin:r[1]+margin+1]
        x_patch[index_patch, :, :, :] = patch
        y_patch[index_patch] = y[r[0]-margin, r[1]-margin]
        index_patch += 1
    del margin, x_zeros, row_range, col_range, patch
    return x_patch.astype(np.float16), y_patch.astype(np.float16)
```

I want the same function to be converted into a generator by including one additional function argument "batch_size". This should generate batch_size image patches every time.

```
def pad_zeros(x, margin=2):
    # x is a numpy array with shape of: (width, height, bands)
    new_x = np.zeros((x.shape[0]+2*margin, x.shape[1]+2*margin, x.shape[2]))
    new_x[margin:x.shape[0]+margin, margin:x.shape[1]+margin, :] = x
    return new_x
```

for example,

```
X = np.array([[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 , 1],
              [2, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 5 , 4],
              [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8],
              [3, 2, 1, 3, 0, 9, 1 , 0],
              [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6 , 8],
              [0, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1 , 0]).reshape(1, 7, 8)

Y = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 , 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 , 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 , 0]).reshape(1, 7, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this then? Basically to make a generator, you need to use the keyword `yield` instead of return. See this [blog](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) for examples.

```
def patch_generator(x, y, window_size, batch_size=64):
    # x and y are numpy arrays with shape of: (bands, height, width)
    # generates image patch of shape (patches, size, size, bands)
    # and a ground truth patch of shape (patches,)

    x = x.reshape((x.shape[1], x.shape[2], x.shape[0]))
    y = y.reshape((y.shape[1], y.shape[2], y.shape[0]))
    if window_size % 2 == 0:
        margin = int(window_size/2)
    else:
        margin = int((window_size - 1) / 2)
    x_zeros = pad_zeros(x, margin)

    row_range = range(margin, x_zeros.shape[0] - margin)
    col_range = range(margin, x_zeros.shape[1] - margin)

    # Prepare vectors with batch_size entries
    x_patch = np.zeros((batch_size, window_size, window_size, x.shape[2]))
    y_patch = np.zeros(batch_size)

    for index_patch,r in enumerate(product(row_range, col_range)):

        if window_size % 2 == 0:
            patch = x_zeros[r[0] - margin:r[0] + margin,
                            r[1] - margin:r[1] + margin]
        else:
            patch = x_zeros[r[0] - margin:r[0]+margin+1,
                            r[1] - margin:r[1]+margin+1]

        # Overwrite x_patch and y_patch at each new batch
        x_patch[index_patch % batch_size, :, :, :] = patch
        y_patch[index_patch % batch_size] = y[r[0]-margin, r[1]-margin]

        if ((index_patch+1) % batch_size == 0) or (index_patch==len(row_range)*len(col_range)-1):
            # When we reach batch_size, return the result
            yield (x_patch.astype(np.float16),
                   y_patch.astype(np.float16))
```

And for the test (`patch_fn` is your original function and `patch_generator` is the modified generator version):

```
x = np.array([[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 , 1],
              [2, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 5 , 4],
              [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8],
              [3, 2, 1, 3, 0, 9, 1 , 0],
              [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6 , 8],
              [0, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1 , 0]]).reshape(1, 7, 8)

y = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 , 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 , 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 , 0]]).reshape(1, 7, 8)

window_size = 3
batch_size = 2

res_w_fn = patch_fn(x,y,window_size)
res_w_gen = patch_generator(x,y,window_size,batch_size)

for i,(x,y) in enumerate(res_w_gen):
    x_t,y_t = (res_w_fn[0][i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size,:,:,:],
               res_w_fn[1][i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size])
    if np.sum(x!=x_t)==0 and np.sum(y!=y_t)==0:
        print("Batch #{} - Success".format(i))
    else:
        print("Batch #{} - Fail".format(i))
```

Comment: Thanks Nakor, it works. Let me check it on different scenarios and hopefully no issues I will find.

Comment: It does not generate the remaining patches at the end. When I set batch_size = 1, it generates all the patches correctly. But when I chose for example 3, the last patch is neglected. I want to generate all the patches including the last batch of less size than the selected batch_size.

Comment: it's because the number of combinations is not a multiple of the batch_size. I edited my code to take that into account, let me know if it works better now

Comment: It generates extra patches. In the case of 3, it generates extra 1, and increases by increasing the batch size.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? It generates all the correct patches, and it adds wrong ones in the end?

Comment: They are in the wrong order. The first patch is not as same as what the original function generates. Then I don't know exactly if the extra ones are repeated or else. Trying to find out.

Comment: Just to make sure: to compare the order, you compare `next(patch_generator(x, y, window_size, batch_size=64))` and the first 64 elements of the output of your function, right? If so, I'm surprised. However, it's hard to troubleshoot since I can't run the code (I don't have any example data or the `pad_zeros` function)

Comment: You should edit your post and add the example data. Also, what about `y` ? You only gave me 1 vector

Comment: I just tried it with `patch_generator(x,x,3,2)` and it works, the results are exactly the same (I added the test in my post)

Comment: Yes, with batch_size 2 it works. But generates extra patches when larger batch_size is used, say 3.

Comment: My test seems to work for any batch size (I tried 2,3 and 4). Can you look it up and tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: For the given example in my post, I run your test: 

window_size = 3
batch_size = 5

```


Batch #0 - Success
Batch #1 - Success
Batch #2 - Success
Batch #3 - Success
Batch #4 - Success
Batch #5 - Success
Batch #6 - Success
Batch #7 - Success
Batch #8 - Success
Batch #9 - Success
Batch #10 - Success
Batch #11 - Fail
```

Comment: Your test also fails when batch_size is 3, the last test fails. It works with batch_size = 5 but fails with batch_size = 6.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, I tried with your dataset and I don't get any fail. I don't understand... Are you using python2 or python3?

Comment: I am using Python 3.7

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know. I have the same python version as you, but no error when I run the same thing...

Comment: When len(res_w_fn[0]) % batch_size = !0, it fails.
It only works when the data is divisible on batch_size